# ListView showing only 1 card widget but causes blank space below

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to display only 1 card widget inside a listView.builder, the card is displayed but shows extra space that I couldn't find a way to remove.

There are actually 2 separated listViews, one should contain a single card and another that holds a list of cards.

here's my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
        'Fiche du patient',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      )),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 1,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    elevation: 2.0,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: ListTile(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30, left: 36),
                      title: Text('${widget.patient['nomComplet']}'),
                      subtitle: Text('Médecin: ${widget.patient['medecin']}'),
                      trailing: Text('CH: 107'),
                      leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: docsMesures.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: ListTile(
                      trailing: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                              msg: 'Traitement de la demande');
                        },
                      ),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30, left: 36),
                      title: Text(
                          'Demandée par: ${docsMesures[index]['affectePar']}'),
                      subtitle: Text(
                          'Date limite: ${DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a').format(docsMesures[index]['datePrise'].toDate())}'),
                    ));
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the result as displayed:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are using `Expanded` in a column of two ListViews, this would result in each one of them having half of the height.

removing the `Expanded` from the first `ListView` and adding   `shrinkWrap:true` to it would resolve the problem.

so this code for example:

```
Column(
        children: <Widget>[

          ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 1,
             shrinkWrap: true,

                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    elevation: 2.0,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: ListTile(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30, left: 36),
                      title: Text('asdf'),
                      subtitle: Text('Médecin: '),
                      trailing: Text('CH: 107'),
                      leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
     
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 11,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: ListTile(
                      trailing: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                        onPressed: () {
                    
                        },
                      ),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30, left: 36),
                      title: Text(
                          'Demandée par:'),
                  
                    ));
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      );
```

would give you something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

```dart
Listview.builder(
 shrinkWrap: true,
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Fiche du patient',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          )),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: docsMesures.length +1,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                
                if(index ==0) {
                  return Card(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    elevation: 2.0,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: ListTile(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30, left: 36),
                      title: Text('${widget.patient['nomComplet']}'),
                      subtitle: Text('Médecin: ${widget.patient['medecin']}'),
                      trailing: Text('CH: 107'),
                      leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                else {
                  return Card(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: ListTile(
                        trailing: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                msg: 'Traitement de la demande');
                          },
                        ),
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30, left: 36),
                        title: Text(
                            'Demandée par: ${docsMesures[index-1]['affectePar']}'),
                        subtitle: Text(
                            'Date limite: ${DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a').format(docsMesures[index-1]['datePrise'].toDate())}'),
                      ));
                }
                
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```